# Remote development on Windows over SSH - powershell double-hop authentication

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I set up the remote development over SSH from my windows 10 machine to one of our new Windows 2022 servers. This due the fact that I need to use an other account with extra permissions to be able to run the script on the server.

Everything works fine, I can do 'remote development' over SSH with the other account and write & test powershell code on the server.

When I try to contact an external source in my script (like a fileshare or SQL), I noticed the dreaded "Double-hop" problem pops up.

As the first hop is SSH and not a real WinRM session, I thought this wouldn't be a problem?

Can I force VsCode/Powershell to not see the SSH connection as the first hop?
Or is this something Microsoft changed/enforced for security reasons?

By the way, I'm using Powershell 7 on both client and server

Comment: Whether SSH or WinRM, it's the OS on the first jump box that knows this is a remote session. If you want to be able to pass credentials off to a second box you'll need to look into enabling [CredSSP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.2). We do this to support a number of things; example: remoting into box A, and making box A grab some software from box B to do an install. Always disable CredSSP afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Whether SSH or WinRM, it's the OS on the first jump box that knows this is a remote session. If you want to be able to pass credentials off to a second box you'll need to look into enabling CredSSP.

To enable on your Windows server:

> `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server -Force -ErrorAction Stop`

This should then allow you to access secondary servers. We do this to support a number of things; example: remoting into box A, and making box A grab some software from box B to do an install.

**Always disable CredSSP afterwards:**

> `Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role server -ErrorAction Stop`